# How do I make the return OBJECT of a method generic?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, return-type

I need to do somthing like below code, but new T() does not work. It says 
"Cannot create an instance of variable type T because it does not have a new() constraint."

```
public static T MapToBaseDropDown2<T>(this GenericDropDownData dd) where T : BaseDropDown
{
    return new T() //FAILS
    {
        Id = dd.Id,
        Description = dd.Description
    };
}
```

BaseDropDown is the base class for 3 childs that are entities mapped with EntityFramework (code first), so it may be better keep it as simple as possible.

Now it is not abstract due to some implementations that I tried, but if possible it will be.

```
public class BaseDropDown
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Google "new constraint" - find answer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-constraint

Comment: What is `BaseDropDown`? Show how it´s defined.

Comment: It's because your extension method may apply on a class that doesn't have a constructor, or non-public constructor, or a constructor with required parameters. Use `new()` constraint and you will be sure that the instance using your method have a public constructor without any parameters.

Comment: @HimBromBeere  I've just added what BaseDropDown is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This also works, just adding the `new()` constraint directly to T (not to BaseDropDown)

```
public static T MapToBaseDropDown3<T>(this GenericDropDownData dd) where T : BaseDropDown, new()
{
    return new T()
    {
        Id = dd.Id,
        Description = dd.Description
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Calling `new T()` assumes that every type *has* a parameterless-constructor, which doesn´t seem to be the case here. Even if your base-class `BaseDropDown` has such a constructor that isn´t guranteed for all its subclasses, in particular abstract ones:

```
class BaseDropDown
{
    public BaseDropDown() { /* see parameterless-constructor exists */ }
}
abstract class MyClass : BaseDropDown
{
    public MyClass() { ... }
}
```

Now you could use the `new`-constraint to *exclude* abstract classes:

```
public static T MapToBaseDropDown2<T>(this GenericDropDownData dd) where T : BaseDropDown, new()
```

That constraint will onlx allow classes that inherit `BaseDropDown` *and*  are instantiable using a parameterless constructor.

Answer (score 1):

The `BaseDropDown` class needs to have the `new()` constraint applied like this:

```
public class BaseDropDown<T> where T : SomeClass, new()
{
}
```

The `new()` constraint must always be applied last.  See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-constraint) for more details.

Comment: `BaseDropDown` doesn´t seem to be generic, but `MapToBaseDropDown2`  is.

Answer (score -1):

Using reflection works fine:

```
public static T MapToBaseDropDown2<T>(this GenericDropDownData dd) where T : BaseDropDown
{
    T entityDd = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
    entityDd.Id = dd.Id;
    entityDd.Description = dd.Description;
    return entityDd;
}
```

Comment: You should use the `new()` constraint rather than this technique. That way, if you try and do this with a `T` that lacks a parameterless constructor it will fail at **compile** time. Your code will compile fine but fail at **run** time.